# Echo to Serialport

Tags: linux, serial-port, echo

I have a web application running on an Raspberry Pi Server (Debian).

The application send a simple echo over the commandline to a serialport.

I think the serialport is configured correctly.

The Echo:

`echo "G0030af13403b1610097ee8" > /dev/ttyUSB0`

When i send the command nothing happend.

But when i open a cat session in a other terminal everything works fine !

`cat /dev/ttyUSB0`

I think the serialport does not open with the `echo`  alone ...

Is there a way to open the port and send the echo in one commandline ?

Comment: I suspect that `/dev/ttyUSB0` is a regular file rather than a character special file (device node). Can you [edit] the question to include the output of `stat /dev/ttyUSB0`?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happened"? Did the `echo` command hang? Did it return immediately? Did it return after a short while? Was there an error message? What did you expect to happen (but didn't)?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all i have found a solution ...

I have to run cat in background.

`cat /dev/ttyusb0 &`

then echo to it .

`echo "G0030af13403b1610097ee8" > /dev/ttyUSB0`

and kill the `cat` process.

I have solved it in a litte shell script:

```
cat /dev/ttyUSB0 &
bgPid=$!
echo "G0030af13403b1610097ee8" > /dev/ttyUSB0
kill $bgPid
```

Comment: Please use the correct button to answer your question.